# Angular Lazy-Load modules: "duplicated" components

Tags: angular

We're developing a "big" application that has a main module with the menu, and the rest, is lazy-loaded from the routes. Our approach was to put in the parent module only the most basic things, and declare the components at child-module level.

But something happens when you traverse through different modules with this approach:

[image]

I tried to declare the components at the parent module. Here you have two pastebins, one with our current 3 modules (parent + 2 child) in the old state, and another after the change. As I'm not very sure if this change has been correctly performed, it would be nice if somebody who deeply understands about NgModule, can check it out!

Old version: VRJ8K6v9

New version: yuynRqia

(just type the address of pastebin and use that identifier; stackoverflow doesn't let me directly reference them for some weird reason).

So, with the new version, as you could guess, something is not working well. Basically, when loading any of the routes that brings us to any of both child modules, I get the following error:

[image]

Anybody knows what I'm doing wrong? Am I missing something when moving the declarations to the parent component? Thank you!

EDIT:

After trying the solution of creating a shared module with the components, I'm even more confused now. It's not working at all. This is what I did:

> I removed all the component declarations from both child modules to the new module
>   After that, declared all of them in the new shared module.
>   Also imported CommonModule and BrowserModule in this module (tried without the latter one too, but didn't have any affect).

Nothing seems to work, since I'm getting nonsense errors as:

[image]

I seriously need some help in this.

Comment: Look at this url https://arifwicaksana.net/mitigating-error-type-is-part-of-the-declarations-of-2-modules-in-angular/

Comment: I'm testing it right now, but I'm having some errors. Will tell you later how this works

Comment: @AkshayGarg it's not working at all :/. I really don't get this Angular module system...